# How to enable a button if an item in a listbox is selected

Tags: c#, listbox

I tried this but it doesn't work. They're still greyed out even when I select stuff.

```
btnVoirFiche.Enabled = false;
btnEchangerJoueur.Enabled = false;
if (lstJoueurs.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            btnVoirFiche.Enabled = true;
            btnEchangerJoueur.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

Comment: into this : private void frmPoolHockeyLNH_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: Does the listbox's SelectedIndexChanged event point to that method?

Comment: how do I make sure ? probly since I load the elements from the same method.

Comment: When you have the designer open, select the listbox, open the properties window. Near the top will be an icon (in VS 2012 it's a lightning bolt) that, when clicked shows the events. Then scroll down to `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to handle the ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged event, and within your handler you're going to check if the specific value is the selected one, and then set you button's enable property accordingly.

Something like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        btnVoirFiche.Enabled = true;
        btnEchangerJoueur.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
       //whatever you need to test for
    }
}
```

Cheers

EDIT: I'm not too sure what your logic for button's enabled property is, so my answer is pretty generic. If you add details to you question, I'll adapt accordingly.

Comment: Thanks this was perfect, do you also know how to make an hiden element appear with another command (when selected) ? ex: how to make btnVoirFiche.Hide appear.

Comment: btnVoirFiche.Visible = true;

Answer (score 1):

Hook into SelectedIndexChanged event and put your code inside of it

```
private void lstJoueurs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstJoueurs.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        btnVoirFiche.Enabled = true;
        btnEchangerJoueur.Enabled = true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, and using mrlucmorin's answer, you could use the listbox's `SelectedItem` which will return `null` if nothing is selected.